# simplifying Boolean expression A'BC + AB'C + ABC'

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Need help here, whats the simplified form of this Boolean expression? I'm a little confused about this, help me guys!

A'BC + AB'C + ABC'

Answer (score 1):

```
ABC A'BC + AB'C + ABC'
000 0
001 0
010 0
011 1
100 0
101 1
110 1
111 0
```

This cannot be simplified, see [**Karnaugh map*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)*.

But using other operators, there are simpler forms:

- Exclusive OR ^: **A'BC + A(B^C)**
- Bit count: **#[A, B, C] = 2**